# How to create infinitely incrementing elements efficiently?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, append, infinite

Let's say I have a button on an html page and that button appends content to a page with jQuery (within a **jQuery Mobile** environment).

I need a way to **append infinitely many content divs** that works like a counter system so the first one produced can be labeled the first content div
then the next one can be labeled the second and so on.

**I tried doing this with unique ids that incremented but it became a nightmare.**

How so?

Lets say I add **3** content divs, but I don't like content **#2** so I **delete #2**. Then **Content #3 becomes Content #2**, so every single element has to have their id changed.

That's not as complicated when there's only 3 content divs, **but let's say there's 30 content divs:** you delete content #2 and now the other 28 content divs have to have all of their unique ids changed.

And to top it all off, within each content div, **let's say there's 30 elements that also need to have all of their unique ids changed.**

Thus, nightmare.

**EDIT: Here's some of my code from the last time I tried to do this, as requested:**

```
//Question Type Visibility
$(document).on("pageinit","#createSurvey", function(){

$("#container").empty();

//Reset qCount
qCount = 0;

$(document).undelegate('#addQ', 'click').delegate('#addQ', 'click', function() {

    //Increment question counter
    qCount++;

    $('\
        <div id="newQ' + qCount + '" style="text-align: center !important; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) !important;">\
            <h2 id="num' + qCount + '" style="color: #52D273;">Question ' + qCount + '</h2>\
            \
            <!--Question Title-->\
            <label id="qTitleLabel' + qCount + '" for="qTitle" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                Question Title:\
            </label>\
            <input type="text" name="qTitle[]" id="qTitle' + qCount + '" placeholder="Question Title" required>\
                <br>\
            <h3 id="cat' + qCount + '" style="color: #46BCE1;">Question Category</h3>\
            \
            <!--Question Category-->\
            <label id="qCatLabel' + qCount + '" for="qCat' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                Question Category:\
            </label>\
            <select name="addQCat[]" id="addQCat' + qCount + '" class="' + qCount + '">\
                <option selected disabled hidden value=\'\'>Pick a Category</option>\
                <option value="Category 1">Category 1</option>\
                <option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>\
                <option value="Category 3">Category 3</option>\
                <option value="Category 4">Category 4</option>\
                <option value="Category 5">Category 5</option>\
            </select>\
                <br>\
            <h3 id="type' + qCount + '" style="color: #46BCE1;">Question Type</h3>\
            \
            <!--Question Type-->\
            <label id="qTypeLabel' + qCount + '" for="addQType' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                Question Type:\
            </label>\
            <select name="addQType[]" id="addQType' + qCount + '" class="' + qCount + '">\
                <option selected disabled hidden value=\'\'>Pick a Type</option>\
                <option value="smallTextDiv">Small Text</option>\
                <option value="tORfDiv">True or False?</option>\
                <option value="dropdownDiv">Dropdown</option>\
                <option value="numDiv">Number</option>\
                <option value="radDiv">Radio Buttons</option>\
                <option value="largeTextDiv">Large Text</option>\
                <option value="checkDiv">Checkboxes</option>\
            </select>\
            \
            <!--Small Text-->\
            <div id="smallTextDiv' + qCount + '" class="types' + qCount + '">\
                <h2 id="previewSmallText' + qCount + '">Preview</h2>\
                <label id="addQSmallTextLabel' + qCount + '" for="addQSmallText' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Preview:\
                </label>\
                <input type="text" name="addQSmallText' + qCount + '" id="addQSmallText' + qCount + '" placeholder="The user would type their answer in here...">\
            </div>\
            \
            <!--True/False-->\
            <div id="tORfDiv' + qCount + '" class="types' + qCount + '">\
                <h2 id="previewTOrF' + qCount + '">Preview</h2>\
                <div id="switchContainer' + qCount + '">\
                    <label id="switchLabel' + qCount + '" for="switch' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                        Preview (A.K.A. On/Off):\
                    </label>\
                    <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="switch' + qCount + '" id="switch' + qCount + '" data-on-text="True" data-off-text="False">\
                </div>\
                \
                <label id="replaceOffLabel' + qCount + '" for="replaceOff' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Replace Off:\
                </label>\
                <input type="text" name="replaceOff' + qCount + '" id="replaceOff' + qCount + '" placeholder="Replace Off Text">\
                \
                <label id="replaceOnLabel' + qCount + '" for="replaceOn' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Replace On:\
                </label>\
                <input type="text" name="replaceOn' + qCount + '" id="replaceOn' + qCount + '" placeholder="Replace On Text">\
                \
                <label id="replaceTextLabel' + qCount + '" for="replaceText' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Replace Text:\
                </label>\
                <input type="button" value="Replace Text" id="replaceText' + qCount + '" class="' + qCount + '" style="background-color: blue;">\
                \
                <!--True or False: Off Text-->\
                <input type="hidden" name="offTxt[]" id="offTxt' + qCount + '">\
                \
                <!--True or False: On Text-->\
                <input type="hidden" name="onTxt[]" id="onTxt' + qCount + '">\
            </div>\
            \
            <!--Dropdown-->\
            <div id="dropdownDiv' + qCount + '" class="types' + qCount + '">\
                <h2 id="previewDropDown' + qCount + '">Preview</h2>\
                <div id="dropdownContainer' + qCount + '" class= ' + qCount + '>\
                    <label id="addQDropDownLabel' + qCount + '" for="addQDropDown' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                        Preview:\
                    </label>\
                    <select name="addQDropDown' + qCount + '" id="addQDropDown' + qCount + '" class="0">\
                        <option selected disabled hidden value=\'\'>Make your Choice</option>\
                        <option value="Choice 1">Choice 1</option>\
                    </select>\
                </div>\
                    <br>\
                <label id="addChoiceLabel' + qCount + '" for="addChoice' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Add Choice:\
                </label>\
                <input type="button" value="Add Choice" id="addChoice' + qCount + '" class="' + qCount + '" style="background-color: gold;">\
                \
                <div id="choicesContainer' + qCount + '"></div>\
                <label id="updateChoicesLabel' + qCount + '" for="updateChoices' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Update Choices:\
                </label>\
                <input type="button" value="Update Choices" id="updateChoices' + qCount + '" class="' + qCount + '" style="background-color: blue;">\
                \
                <input type="hidden" name="choiceCounter[]" id="choiceCounter' + qCount + '">\
            </div>\
            \
            <!--Number-->\
            <div id="numDiv' + qCount + '" class="types' + qCount + '">\
                <h2 id="previewNum' + qCount + '">Preview</h2>\
                <div id="numContainer' + qCount + '" class="' + qCount + '">\
                    <label id="addQNumLabel' + qCount + '" for="addQNum' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                        Number:\
                    </label>\
                    <input type="range" name="addQNum' + qCount + '" id="addQNum' + qCount + '" value="5" min="0" max="10"  data-popup-enabled="true" data-highlight="true">\
                </div>\
                \
                <label id="replaceMinLabel' + qCount + '" for="replaceMin' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Replace Min:\
                </label>\
                <input type="number" name="replaceMin' + qCount + '" id="replaceMin' + qCount + '" placeholder="Replace Minimum Number">\
                \
                <label id="replaceMaxLabel' + qCount + '" for="replaceMax' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Replace Max:\
                </label>\
                <input type="number" name="replaceMax' + qCount + '" id="replaceMax' + qCount + '" placeholder="Replace Maximum Number">\
                \
                <label id="replaceNumsLabel' + qCount + '" for="replaceNums' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Replace Nums:\
                </label>\
                <input type="button" value="Replace Min/Max" id="replaceNums' + qCount + '" class="' + qCount + '" style="background-color: blue;">\
                \
                <!--Number: Min Text-->\
                <input type="hidden" name="minTxt[]" id="minTxt' + qCount + '">\
                \
                <!--Number: Max Text-->\
                <input type="hidden" name="maxTxt[]" id="maxTxt' + qCount + '">\
            </div>\
            \
            <!--Radio Buttons-->\
            <div id="radDiv' + qCount + '" class="types' + qCount + '">\
                <h2 id="previewRadio' + qCount + '">Preview</h2>\
                <div id="radsContainer' + qCount + '" class="0">\
                    <fieldset id="radsSet' + qCount + '" data-role="controlgroup">\
                        <label for="rad1' + qCount + '">\
                            Button 1\
                        </label>\
                        <input type="radio" name="rad1' + qCount + '" id="rad1' + qCount + '" class="rads' + qCount + '" value="rad1">\
                    </fieldset>\
                </div>\
                    <br>\
                <label id="addRadLabel' + qCount + '" for="addRad' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Add Radio Button:\
                </label>\
                <input type="button" value="Add Radio Button" id="addRad' + qCount + '" class="' + qCount + '" style="background-color: gold;">\
                <div id="btnContainer' + qCount + '" />\
                <label id="updateRadsLabel' + qCount + '" for="updateRads' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Update Radio Buttons:\
                </label>\
                <input type="button" value="Update Radio Buttons" id="updateRads' + qCount + '" class="' + qCount + '" style="background-color: blue;">\
                \
                <input type="hidden" name="radCounter[]" id="radCounter' + qCount + '">\
            </div>\
            \
            <!--Large Text-->\
            <div id="largeTextDiv' + qCount + '" class="types' + qCount + '">\
                <h2 id="previewLargeText' + qCount + '">Preview</h2>\
                <label for="addQLargeText' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Large Text:\
                </label>\
                <textarea name="addQLargeText' + qCount + '" id="addQLargeText' + qCount + '" placeholder="The user would type their answer in here..."></textarea>\
            </div>\
            \
            <!--Checkbox-->\
            <div id="checkDiv' + qCount + '" class="types' + qCount + '">\
                <h2 id="previewCheck' + qCount + '">Preview</h2>\
                <div id="checksContainer' + qCount + '" class="0">\
                    <fieldset id="checksSet' + qCount + '" data-role="controlgroup">\
                        <label for="check1' + qCount + '">\
                            Checkbox 1</label>\
                        <input type="checkbox" name="check1' + qCount + '" id="check1' + qCount + '" class="checks' + qCount + '" value="check1">\
                    </fieldset>\
                </div>\
                    <br>\
                <label id="addChecksLabel' + qCount + '" for="addChecks' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Add Checkbox Button:\
                </label>\
                <input type="button" value="Add Checkbox" id="addCheck' + qCount + '" class="' + qCount + '" style="background-color: gold;">\
                \
                <div id="boxContainer' + qCount + '" />\
                <label id="updateChecksLabel' + qCount + '" for="updateChecks' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Update Checkboxes:\
                </label>\
                <input type="button" value="Update Checkboxes" id="updateChecks' + qCount + '" class="' + qCount + '" style="background-color: blue;">\
                \
                <input type="hidden" name="checkCounter[]" id="checkCounter' + qCount + '">\
            </div>\
            <br>\
            <div id="delQDiv' + qCount + '">\
                <label id="delQLabel' + qCount + '" for="delQ' + qCount + '" class="ui-hidden-accessible">\
                    Delete Question\
                </label>\
                <input type="button" value="Delete Question" id="delQ' + qCount + '" class="'+ qCount +'" style="background-color: red !important;"></div>\
            </div>').hide().appendTo("#container").fadeIn(1000).enhanceWithin();
```

Comment: Post you code here. Give us a glimpse into your nightmare.

Comment: Do the elements need to have unique IDs? Please describe what you're ultimately aiming to achieve. There might be a more effective way of handling your situation.

Comment: @VictorLevin Code posted as requested.

Comment: @showdev yes I believe they need unique ids because a ton of the elements within each content div need to be stored in a database in the order that they're entered into the form (therefore if there's 3 questions in a survey, then all the elements related to the first question will be identified by their ids, and then stored, then all the elements related to the second question will be identified by their ids, and then stored, and so on...

Comment: You're right, this is a major nightmare you created for yourself. Perhaps if you explain how you submit/store survey data in DB it might give me some idea where you went wrong.  I far as I can see, you don't need to increment ids, you just need to count instances of the question container `div` upon form submission. And when user deletes a question in the middle, simply change the `h2` text again by iterating through container `div`s....

Answer (score 0):

Does it really matter if your id numbers are not contiguous? If it does, wait until you do a save then renumber them.

if you just want to know the number then do something like:

```
var count =   $("div").length;
```

Just make sure that

Comment: I believe they have to be contiguous because let's say this is a survey form where the user can add questions; user adds 3 questions, doesn't like second question, so the user deletes the second question. Then question #3 has to be renumbered, as does all the individual elements within question 3.